# Header declaration "The chicken or the egg"

Tags: c++, header

For a project, I have to write a container class and the elements, where the elements need knowledge about the container they are in.Also the creation should be done by a factory methode in the container As this is easy if you use a header and a cpp file, it seem impossible for me if you (like me) only allowed to use one header. Here are a example of the problem:

```
class myContainer;
class myElement;

class myContainer
{
  public:
    myElement *createElement()
    {
      myElement *me =new myElement(this); 
      // do some adding to list stuff
      return me;
    }

    int askMyContainer()
    {
       return 42;
    }
};

class myElement
{
  public:
    myElement(myContainer *parent)
    {
     pcontainer=parent;
    }

    int userAskingSomething()
    {
     return pcontainer->askMyContainer();
    }
 protected:
  myContainer *pcontainer;
};
```

The class myContainer need knowledge about myElement, that is why myElement hat to be before myContainer, but myElement need knowledge about myContainer.

Comment: What's going wrong?  Build error?  Where?

Comment: Why don't you declare the function inside the class and give definition after both class declaration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to split the class definition and the methods definitions into separate pieces for at least one of the classes.

For example, first define the `myContainer` class (i.e. the class and its variables/functions but *not* the implementation of those functions). Then have the `myElement` class. Follow this with the actual implementations of the `myContainer` member functions (marked `inline` if you want them in the header file).

Comment: Yeah, +1 I found the same solution during writing my question.

Comment: Äh, no, my approach is different. Marking them inline solves the problem if I wrote the implementation in the header? I got to try this...

Answer (score 2):

You might split the declarations and definitions using additional files to resolve the circle:

```
// File myContainer.h:

#include "myElement.h"

class myContainer
{
    public:
    myElement *createElement();
    int askMyContainer();
};
#include "myElement.hcc"


// File myContainer.hcc:

#include "myElement.h"

// inline myContainer functions


// File myElement.h

class myContainer;
class myElement
{
    public:
    myElement(myContainer *parent);
    int userAskingSomething();
    protected:
    myContainer *pcontainer;
};
#include "myElement.hcc"


// File myElement.hcc

#include "myContainer.h"

// inline myElement functions
```

Answer (score 0):

During writing the question, I got one idea how to resolve it, and that is inheritance.
Like

```
class myContainerBase
{
  pulbic:
  int askMyContainer()
  {
     return 42;
  }
};

//...
class myElement 
{
  public:
   myElement(myContainerBase *parent)
   {
     pcontainer=parent;
   }
//...

class myContainer:public my ContainerBase
{
//...
```

Does anyone have a better way? Or is that okay?

Joachim Pileborg got the best answer for me. In his last sentence is something I did not known before. Here my working example for there rest of us :-)

```
class myContainer;
class myElement;

class myContainer
{
  public:
    myElement *createElement();

    int askMyContainer()
    {
       return 42;
    }
};

class myElement
{
  public:
    myElement(myContainer *parent)
    {
     pcontainer=parent;
    }

    int userAskingSomething()
    {
     return pcontainer->askMyContainer();
    }
 protected:
  myContainer *pcontainer;
};


inline myElement *myContainer::createElement()
{
  myElement *me =new myElement(this); 
  // do some adding to list stuff
  return me;
}
```

Comment: It'd be simpler to do what the other answer suggests - e.g. don't write your myContainer::createElement() inside the class definition, but put it later, as you would if you had a .cpp file.